# Handle SIGTERM with the cluster module

Tags: node.js

Hi there where can i find the source code for signal handling when using the cluster module? I want to handle a SIGTERM so that i can "graceful" close the http server but as soon as the master process receives this signal the http server stops listening.

"Termination" handler (This function gets called when SIGTERM or SIGINT)

```
function handleTermination(httpServer?: http.Server) {
    if (Store.receive<symbol, boolean>(STORE_KEYS.isTerminating)) {
        return
    }

    Store.store<symbol, boolean>(STORE_KEYS.isTerminating, true)

    if (httpServer) {
        if (!httpServer.listening || isDevelopment) {
            closeAll()
            process.exit(0)
            return
        }

        setTimeout(() => {
            if (process.env.GRACEFUL_SHUTDOWN !== undefined) {
                gracefulCloseSockets()
            }

            httpServer.close(endProcess)
        }, 5000)
    } else {
        endProcess()
    }
}
```

Example router handler

```
function timerHandler(_req: RequestObject, respond: ResponseHandler) {
    setTimeout(() => respond('ok'), 2000)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved my problem. Here's the code which solved my problem.

**master.js**

```
function close(callback) {
  if (!cluster.isMaster) {
    return
  }

  const promiseArray = []
  const workerIds = Object.keys(cluster.workers)

  for (const workerId of workerIds) {
    const worker = cluster.workers[workerId]

    worker.send('shutdown')
    worker.disconnect()

    promiseArray.push(new Promise((resolve) => {
      let resolved = false

      worker.once('exit', () => (!resolved && resolve(), resolved = true))
      setTimeout(() => (!resolved && resolve(), worker.kill('SIGTERM'), resolved = true), 4000)
    }))
  }

  Promise.all(promiseArray).then(callback)
}
```

**worker.js**

```
function terminateWorker(server) {
  if (server && server.listening) {
    Store.store(STORE_KEYS.isTerminating, true)
    gracefulCloseSockets()
    server.close(endProcess)
  } else {
    endProcess()
  }
}
```

**Explanation**

1. When the master receives a "SIGTERM" he calls the `close` function (excerpt above)
2. The worker receives the "shutdown" message and calls the `terminateWorker` function (excerpt above). This function closes the `http.Server` and waits for all sockets to finish.

Answer (score 0):

How about process.on( "exit", cb) or process.on( "beforeExit", cb ) ?

Comment: Thank you, i'll check this asap and report back.

Comment: When i use those events the http server is already closed. So this isn't what i want to accomplish.